# try to hide downloaded videos of video streaming App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, youtube, android-download-manager, netflix

I'm trying to create an AWS video streaming App on Android. but I have to download the video for offline streaming. but thing is that I want to hide the video files, like youtube or NetFlix.so if anyone can explain how to hide downloaded files....pleasse help me . Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use app-specific files directory, no one can see files...
You can access files directory via,

in Kotlin

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, filename)
```

in Java

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

for more details https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific